# Additional information: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near :

Tags: c#, wpf

guys i'm trying to execute this Multi login page and in c# wpf i'm a beginner in programming and i followed each step from youtube channels and couldn't make it work any help !!

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=root**strong text**\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Log-In;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Login where username"+txt_usr.Text+"password"+txt_pass.Text+"", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        string cmbitemvalue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
              if(dt.Rows[i]["usertype"].ToString()==cmbitemvalue)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("you are login as " + dt.Rows[i][2]);
                    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        Admin aa = new Admin();
                            aa.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }else
                    {
                        Student ss = new Student();
                        ss.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is wrong -> username"+txt_usr.Text+"password"+txt_pass.Text+"" Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: +1 for Sandris's note. Your Select statement shouldn't be building a string the way you are because of something called Sql Injection.  Refactor your code based on @SandrisB's notes and give us an update.

Comment: SQL injection apart (that's very important, learn to fix it, fix this now, even if this is just homework, and never do that again), the SQL syntax for a `WHERE` condition is `SELECT .... WHERE Username='foo' AND Password='secretbar'` . Depending on what you have in your variables, it can lead to this error. Use SQL parameters as suggested by the link above, and make sure the result uses the parameter, with an 'equal' = sign

Comment: @Pac0 You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @KeithStein you're right, done

Answer (score 1):

## Your SQL Query you are creating looks invalid

Let's focus on the username part.

I can imagine that `txt_usr.Text` contains the username, let's say `leo`. The way you wrote it, this would give :

```
"select * from Login where username"+txt_usr.Text
```

which is :

```
select * from Login where usernameleo
```

(hence, the cause of the error, there is no condition here, just a name of an invalid column)

The correct query looks like this :

```
select * from Login where username='leo'
```

or this

```
select * from Login where username="leo"
```

depending on the database kind you use (SQL Server, SQLite, MYSQL, Postgresql, etc....).

If you want 2 conditions, the proper syntax is (usually) to use `AND`

```
select * from Login where username="leo" and password='secret'
```

So, you are missing an equal sign, the boolean AND, and proper quotation.

That's not all.

## !!! Your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection, use .NET SQL Parameters !!!

[image: obligatory XKCD illustration of SQL injection]

*illustration : [https://xkcd.com/327/](https://xkcd.com/327/_)*

Instead of using *whatever the user enters in the text box* (including potential malicious code) the correct way to do it in C# is to use [SQL parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8).

These will take care of sanitizing the input for you, and it will also be clearer in the code, and you don't need to worry about quotation :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Login where username=@username AND password=@password", con);
cmd.AddParameter('@username', txt_usr.Text);
cmd.AddParameter('@password', txt_pass.Text);
```

Even if this is homework, we have all seen too many websites / companies hacked and data destroyed or stolen so easily because this kind of vulnerability has been made possible, I think most db and security experts here are constantly stressing that you need to learn this fast, and never use unsanitized input for sql queries, ever.

## Other security consideration

The fact that the password seem to be in clear text in the database is also a source of concern, please search about "clear text password" and "properly hash and salt passwords" to learn more about this.

But this a bit more work to understand than the SQL parameters, and a few lines of additional lines of code in your program.